# Hibernate @Formula annotation doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I use @Formula annotation in Hibernate 4.3.7 but it doesn't load value.

```
@Entity
@AccessType(Type.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "ENTITY_B_TABLE")
public class EntityB extends AbstractEntity {
    //
    // ...
    //

    private EntityB parentEntityB;

    @Formula(value = "SELECT * FROM ENTITY_B_TABLE WHERE TYPE IN ('A', 'B', 'C') AND ROWNUM=1 CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ID = ID START WITH ID = :id")
    public EntityB getParentEntityB() {
        return parentEntityB;
    }

    public void setParentEntityB(EntityB parentEntityB) {
        this.parentEntityB = parentEntityB;
    }

}
```

In that case I have an error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: my.package.EntityB, 
>   at table: ENTITY_B_TABLE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Formula(
>   SELECT * FROM ENTITY_B_TABLE WHERE LEVEL_NAME IN ('A', 'B', 'C') AND
>   ROWNUM=1 CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ID = ID START WITH ID = :id )]

In SQL "id" is id of current EntityB.
If I add a @Transient annotation to getParentEntityB method there are no mistakes but parentEntityB is null.
There is no column for parentEntityB in ENTITY_B_TABLE and we don't want create it, we want load it dynamicly. And we can garantee that parentEntityB is not null allways according to select.

Is there a better method to solve this problem?
(I also tried @Loader without success)

> Try to move @Formula over the field. In my previous experience, I saw a > lot of them being only over fields.

The result is same.

> I found somethinf like this: forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=956537 - maybe that could help? 
>   In short - @OneToOne may be required.

With (@OneToOne or @ManyToOne) and without @Transient there is no exception, but parentEntityB still equals to null.

Comment: Try to move @Formula over the field. In my previous experience, I saw a lot of them being only over fields.

Comment: Thanks, I tried already with the same result.

Comment: I found somethinf like this: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=956537 - maybe that could help? In short - @OneToOne may be required.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if Formula can be used to return an actual object.
From the documentation it looks like it returns primitive read only values only

```
@Formula("obj_length * obj_height * obj_width")
```

public long getObjectVolume()

One more example, but again returning a primitive value only.

```
<property name="totalPrice"
formula="( SELECT SUM (li.quantity*p.price) FROM LineItem li, Product p
            WHERE li.productId = p.productId
            AND li.customerId = customerId
            AND li.orderNumber = orderNumber )"/>
```